# How do I clone structure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For example suppose I have a table M2011_03 and I wish to copy the structure but not the data into a table M2011_04. M2011_04 currently does not exist. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

More information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1):

either 
a) paste the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE M2011_03` to create the '04 one.

or

b)

```
CREATE TABLE M2011_04 SELECT * FROM M2011_03;
TRUNCATE TABLE M2011_04;
```